# Using 'this' in objects methods in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, this, javascript-objects

I am learning JavaScript and to improve my knowledge of the language I have been trying to understand how this [todo-list application](https://maze-stealer.glitch.me/#/all) works. The source code is [available here](https://github.com/gordonmzhu/todomvc/blob/master/examples/jquery/js/app.js).

Overall, I have the feeling that I understand the code fairly well. There is just one thing that bothers me : at line 43, in the 'init' method of the 'App' object, the following happens:

```
this.todos = util.store('todos-jquery');
```

To give you context, here is the begining of the 'App' object and of the 'init' method:

```
var App = {
    init: function () {
        this.todos = util.store('todos-jquery');    // <= this line
        this.todoTemplate = Handlebars.compile($('#todo-template').html());
        this.footerTemplate = Handlebars.compile($('#footer-template').html());
        this.bindEvents();
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

What I don't understand is, why would you define 'todos' by using 'this.todos' inside of the 'init' method, and not by putting it directly into the 'App' object as I did below:

```
var App = {
    todos: util.store('todos-jquery'),  // <= this line
    init: function () {
        this.todoTemplate = Handlebars.compile($('#todo-template').html());
        this.footerTemplate = Handlebars.compile($('#footer-template').html());
        this.bindEvents();
        ...
    }
...
}
```

I have been reading about the 'this' keyword in the MDN web docs and in other articles such as [this one](https://www.sitepoint.com/what-is-this-in-javascript/) to try to answer this question myself, but somehow I feel like none of the examples really match the case I described above.

So I got the source code and tried to see if the application still worked after making the above changes. And it does. I am now making the assumption that the two approaches are equivalent : is there any benefits from using one approach rather than the other? Or does it just depend on each developper's programming style?

Comment: What would happen if that block of logic ran before the `util.store('todos-jquery')` existed, or was initialized itself?

Comment: @Taplar I moved the line "todos: util.store('todos-jquery')," below the init method, everything works normally. At the end of the code, the method is called (App.init();), as a way to start the application.

Comment: I'm not saying it will not work like that.  I'm simply giving a suggestion as to why it is possibly common practice to do that in an init method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general when you have:

```
var X = {
  y: z(),
  init: function() {
  }
};
```

This should be equivalent to:

```
var X = {
  init: function() {
    this.y = z();
  }
}
```

Provided you call `X.init()` and are assured that calling `z()` prior to that is not problematic. The end result is that `X.y` is populated with the return values of `z()`.

The second approach, where everything is in `init()`, gives you more control over sequencing and may be preferable from a consistency and simplicity perspective. It does seem arbitrary in this particular case.

In modern JavaScript you should really have:

```
class X {
  constructor() {
  }

  y = z();
}
```

Where then you'd be able to call `let x = new X()` and `x.y()` in turn.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The explanation you gave about sequencing makes a lot of sense in this context, as the init method is called as a 'starter' ( App.init();) toward the end of the code.
As for the modern JavaScript, no iteration of that object is made, so I'm not sure using a constructor and creating an instance of the object with the New keyword would make a lot of sense here. I have the feeling objects in this code are used to organise everything better and make it easy to read through. Would that make sense?

Comment: The example is from 2015 and JavaScript conventions have evolved a lot since that time. for more contemporary examples see Ember, React, Vue and Angular.